# Open .mpb file extension

Tags: file-io, file-extension

I have some .mpb files made by MyPhoneExplorer around 3 years ago. They contain my text message backups which are very important for me.
I have no Sony Erickson device anymore and cannot open them using myphoneexplorer without a Sony Erickson cell phone connected!

Is there any ways to open them without a Sony Erickson phone?

Answer (score 2):

No neeed for reverse engineering, there is a simple way. Open MyPhoneExplorer and go to the `Messages -> Archive`, right click in the list area, then `Import/Export -> Import` and select all your .mpb files. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reverse engineering the format? It may be fairly straightforward to extract at least the text of the messages. Try looking at the file with a text editor, or if it is not all text, use hexdump -C. If you can identify some simple markers that delimit the messages in the file you may then be able to use some combination of grep and sed to extract the messages one per line to another file.

Comment: Damn! I should have read your comment before going through so much trouble trying to install the software and opening the backup. That wouldn't work without a phone being connected, and I didn't want to do that. Now, opening the backup file in a text editor, I was able to find a contact I had lost long back.